# Java 11 and jacorb. ClassNotFoundException: javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub

Tags: java, java-11, jacorb

I am trying to execute my application of java 11 (openjdk) with jacorb 3.9.The application starts executing but crashes complaining about missing :

```
javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub
```

I have included all jacorb libraries in the CLASSPATH

```
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/jacorb.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/jacorb-3.9.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/jacorb-omgapi.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/slf4j-api.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.14.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/jacorb-services.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/picocontainer.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/wrapper.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/antlr.jar:${CLASSPATH}
set CLASSPATH = ${JACORB_PATH}/idl.jar:${CLASSPATH}
```

When executing , I get this:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

I have tried also to set up the JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS with:

```
--module-path ${JACORB_PATH} --add-modules java.corba 
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton
```

But complains about "Two versions of module slf4j.jdk14 found"

The command for executing the program is:

```
java -classpath $CLASSPATH myprog.MYPROG
```

The application was originally written for Java 8 and working OK  with jacorb passing the following  parameters to java command:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=JACORB_PATH
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton
```

The application does not use rmi at all. It is a 'classic' CORBA client. It crashes when trying to resolve the initial reference of the naming Service

Comment: The java.corba module was removed in Java SE 11, see JEP 320 for more on that.

Comment: Thanks, This is why I'm using jacorb.

Comment: Okay but your question includes testing with "--add-modules java.corba" which suggests you are looking for a way to bring it back. I don't know anything about JacORB but the exception suggests that it relies on the JDK to provide the RMI-IIOP classes. Those classes were in the java.corba module.

Comment: I'm just trying to use jacorb. I compiled in java 11 and jacorb 3.9...If I don't use --add-modules, I get the javax error described above, even when all jacorb libs are in CLASSPATH

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the issue have been raised on the project [mailing list](http://lists.spline.inf.fu-berlin.de/pipermail/jacorb-developer/2018-July/000927.html). A workaround is to add on the classpath next to jacorb-3.8.jar and the sfl4j jars these 2:

- jacorb-omgapi-3.8.jar    - from JacORB distribution
- jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec-1.0.6.Final.jar   - from https://github.com/jboss/jboss-rmi-api_spec. This library provides the Java RMI API which was originally used by JacORB from the JRE. ([Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi/jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec/1.0.6.Final))

Comment: That's it. I already had jacorb-omgapi in CLASSPATH but I was missing a java RMI api. MAny thanks indeed for your help

Comment: yes it's because as @AlanBateman said JEP 320 remove the module from JDK

Answer (score 2):

Following JEYs suggestion to substitue the class `javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub` missing in JDKS 9 and later, I composed a stub component from a dozen of relevant JDK-8-classes and this worked. The code coverage of the `javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub` turned out to reduce to the `Stub.toString()` method, which again by context just calls the super class method.

So the solution for JDK 9, 10 (and probably later) is to have an empty Java class surrogate, satisfying the class loader; JacOrb sources could use class ObjectImpl instead, to finally pintch off transient RMI stuff.

```
package javax.rmi.CORBA;

import org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable.ObjectImpl;

/**
 * JacOrb 3.9 surrogate 
 * [Base class from which all RMI-IIOP stubs must inherit.]
 */
public abstract class Stub extends ObjectImpl implements java.io.Serializable
{
}
```

Endorsement of JacOrb libraries and class name replacement is obsolete after JDK 8.

Comment: thank you very much indeed for this!! it works like a charm.
I simply created a jar with the above and added to $CLASSPATH for jaco script.
Simple and effective. No more dependency on jboss rmi lib

Comment: It works like a charm, finally could run CORBA on jdk 17, all credits go to Sam Ginrich